# Merging multiple csv files and plotting continous time on a same plot for all the data

Tags: python, csv, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have created a code which can succefully read and merge multiple csv files in a folder and plot the data. All the files have same column and headers but can be varying rows. Here is my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob
import pandas as pd
import os

def get_merged_csv(flist, **kwargs):
    return pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, **kwargs) for f in flist], ignore_index=True)

path = 'C:\\Users\C253271\Desktop\FTIR Data\Data Files\\' # define path
allfiles =glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))     

column_names = ['Relative Time','Peakat2188', 'water']
data = get_merged_csv(allfiles, index_col=None)
data.columns = column_names

time_in_minutes = pd.to_timedelta(data['Relative Time']).dt.total_seconds() / 60

x=time_in_minutes
y1=data['Peakat2188']
y2=data['water']

fig=plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax1.plot(x,y1,label='Peak at 2188 , color='b') 
ax1.plot(x,y2, label='water', color='r')

ax1.set_ylabel('Volume Fraction',fontsize=10)
ax1.set_xlabel('Absolute time (mins)',fontsize=10)

plt.title('SVC-Evaporator Monitoring', fontsize=20)
ax1.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.8,1.02), loc=3, borderaxespad=0.)
```

Here is my data from three files.

```
FTIR Data1.csv
Relative Time,Peak at 2188 ,water
00:00:51,0.572157,0.179023
00:02:51,0.520037,0.171217
00:04:51,0.551843,0.221285
00:06:50,0.566279,0.209182

FTIR Data2.csv
Relative Time,Peak at 2188 ,water
00:00:45,0.522157,0.169023
00:02:31,0.470037,0.161217
00:04:36,0.501843,0.211285
00:06:20,0.516279,0.199182
00:08:45,-0.027304,0.0061351

FTIR Data3.csv
Relative Time,Peak at 2188,water
00:00:51,0.622157,0.199023
00:02:51,0.570037,0.191217
00:04:51,0.601843,0.241285
```

I want to plot data from all the csv files on one plot with absolute time on xaxis, which i am able to do. When i merge my data, here what it looks like but i want to add every new time into previous ending time starting from second file. For exp, the time in row 3 is the last time of first file which i want to add in row 4 which is the first time of the second file. So now the starting time should be ( 00:06:50 + 00:00:45 = 00:07:35)  then add this time to the next time, row 5 (00:07:35 + 00:02:31 = 00:10:06) of the same file and so on. The idea is to plot the data from three files as continuous. I hope it shouldnt be a big problem and would appreciate if someone can quickly add something in my code to help me. Thanks a million

```
Merged data from 3 files
       Relative Time  Peakat2188     water
    0       00:00:51       0.572157  0.179023
    1       00:02:51       0.520037  0.171217
    2       00:04:51       0.551843  0.221285
    3       00:06:50       0.566279  0.209182
    4       00:00:45       0.522157  0.169023
    5       00:02:31       0.470037  0.161217
    6       00:04:36       0.501843  0.211285
    7       00:06:20       0.516279  0.199182
    8       00:08:45      -0.027304  0.006135
    9       00:00:51       0.622157  0.199023
    10      00:02:51       0.570037  0.191217
    11      00:04:51       0.601843  0.241285
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is it something like this you are looking for?

```
from pathlib import Path

def read_csv_files(csv_files):
    for file in csv_files:
        df = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=None)
        df.columns = ['Relative Time','Peakat2188', 'water']
        yield df

def correct_dataframes(dfs):
    last_time = pd.Timedelta(0)
    for df in dfs:
        df['Relative Time'] += last_time
        last_time = df['Relative Time'].iloc[-1]
        yield df, last_time


data_dir = Path(<data_dir>)
pattern = '*.csv'

files = data_dir.glob(pattern)
dfs = read_csv_files(files)

df_list, end_times = zip(*correct_dataframes(dfs))

df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
```

> df

```
Relative Time   Peakat2188  water
0   00:00:51    0.572157    0.179023
1   00:02:51    0.520037    0.171217
2   00:04:51    0.551843    0.221285
3   00:06:50    0.566279    0.209182
4   00:07:35    0.522157    0.169023
5   00:09:21    0.470037    0.161217
6   00:11:26    0.501843    0.211285
7   00:13:10    0.516279    0.199182
8   00:15:35    -0.027304   0.006135
9   00:16:26    0.622157    0.199023
10  00:18:26    0.570037    0.191217
11  00:20:26    0.601843    0.241285
```

> end_times

```
((Timedelta('0 days 00:06:50'),
  Timedelta('0 days 00:15:35'),
  Timedelta('0 days 00:20:26'))
```

Comment: Thanks @Maarten Fabré. Yes this is exactly what i am looking for. But first how would i create the three data frames (df1, df2, df3) of Relative Time from each csv file. In this case i have only 3 files but what if i have n files? and i want to create the Relative Time data frame from n files. I am struggling a bit in that portion as well if you can also help with that, would be great.

Comment: Sorry @Maarten Fabré, a little correction in my comment. Not just for Relative Time, actually the data frame for each csv file that include all the columns.

Comment: I posted an edit with the globbing included. This relies on the order the datafiles get found. I assume this is lexically sorted. I don't know what this will give between `data9.csv` and `data10.csv`

Comment: Just one more thing @Maarten Fabré... when i plot all this data.. it shows a continuous data which i want but is there anyway that i can put the split or a seperator on the graph which indicates when the first experiment finished and second start and so. Lets just say the data from first csv file is experiment 1 and second csv file experiment 2 and so on. It will be handy for the user when looking the graph. Thanks once again

Comment: I adapted the method to yield both the `df` and the `last_time`, and then the line to get those in a sequence. (I did not test this code, so it it gives errors, let me know)

Comment: I seperated the functions better, so I could test it with the dummy-data